# How to implement single producer, multiple consumer (SPMC) channels in Rust?

Tags: rust

The standard library only has multiple producer, single consumer (MPSC) channels.

That is, if there are 10 consumers, how can every consumer receive a message sent by a single producer?

Comment: *how can every consumer receive a message* — FWIW, I don't believe that's the normal behavior of such channels. Usually it's that *one* consumer gets a message. Think of a "fan-out" pattern, where one thread owns a resource (e.g. network socket) and then hands off the work to one of many threads.

Comment: The trivial implementation would be creating 10 channels and sending the message on all of them.

Comment: There are crates offering such functionality, e.g. [jonhoo/bus](https://github.com/jonhoo/bus) but I didn't look at any in detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [bus](https://github.com/jonhoo/bus) crate that [@CodesInChaos mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893327/how-to-implement-single-producer-multiple-consumer-spmc-channels-in-rust/50896083?noredirect=1#comment88789810_50893327). A working example:

```
extern crate bus;

use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut bus = bus::Bus::new(10);
    let mut receiver1 = bus.add_rx();
    let mut receiver2 = bus.add_rx();
    let mut receiver3 = bus.add_rx();

    let a = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("receiver1 - {}", receiver1.recv().expect("1"));
    });
    let b = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("receiver2 - {}", receiver2.recv().expect("2"));
    });
    let c = thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("receiver3 - {}", receiver3.recv().expect("3"));
    });

    bus.broadcast(42);
    a.join().expect("a");
    b.join().expect("b");
    c.join().expect("c");
}
```

Comment: Nope, not a bot, I just like to curate the [tag:rust] questions in order to learn things and keep the Q&A useful to a maximal number of users.

Comment: (This was useful for me)